# Show index marks in text draft

Tags: makeidx

I am creating an index for a long document using the makeidx package. Everything works fine.

In order to handle the document easier and to have a better overview, it would be very nice to show/mark all the `\index` marks in the text (draft), e.g. by a small dot appearing at the position, or something.

I did not find anything about an option which would allow for something like that. Does anyone have an idea? Any other indexing package or something?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis\index{magnis} dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the purpose of this is just to identify where the 'index-ed' words are? Would `\usepackage{showidx}` be good enough? It prints the index-ed words on the page margins.

Comment: perfect. that is even better then what i had in mind. totally helpful. can you please post it as an answer, so that i can pass you the reputation of the bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your intent is just to identify where the index-ed words are in your manuscript, you can consider using `\usepackage{showidx}`, which usually complements the `makeidx` package.
Its most basic functionality is to print the index-ed words on the right page margins (cf. figure below).

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx} % <--------
\makeindex

\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis\index{magnis} dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: margin index]

Answer (score 1):

I have patched the `\index` command. Now you can adjust the `\indexFormat` command however you want it. As asked for I made it print a dot right above the word. This dot has no width so that it does not affect where lines break.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\let\originalIndex=\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\indexFormat{\originalIndex{#1}}}

\newcommand{\indexFormat}[1]{#1\makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{1.5ex}{\textbf{.}}}}

\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis\index{magnis} dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]